# Catch all page level errors without breaking the page

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, try-catch

I have a c# asp.net project where one ascx inherits from a base ascx. In this base ascx I would like to put a page_error method that logs the error.

I would like that if something in the derived class broke, say a null reference exception, it would not present the user with an error screen. Effectively I want every line of code to act like it is encapsulated inside it's own try catch, so if this null ref exception happened, it would just log the error for that one line and then skip to the next line and keep going.

Is this possible, and how would I go about implementing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. If an UnhandledException is thrown inevitably your Page_Error event will pick up the exception and the normal page execution is interrupted. In general, I think what you are trying to do is BAD practice. I wouldn't go that route.

Comment: I agree. Especially with the Null reference example. Null reference exceptions are almost always programmer bugs. Fix the bugs!

Comment: +1 this is very bad. Reminds me of Classic ASP `on error resume next` which caused all sorts of confusion.

Comment: Not possible does not mean bad practice. :) I have a page that has many independent parts that can fail, but do not want to interrupt the flow of the other parts that do not rely on them. Instead of throwing in a bunch of try catch for a bunch of methods I was just wondering about this route. I thought it would be cool, but I suppose I'll just pick and choose which methods need error logging. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Not possible in this case is because it is bad practice.

Comment: @asawyer I totally agree! But sometimes there could be a disconnect with a DBA making a default value in a column null, and you get the returned value as null and try to toString it...there could be many such instances that only come up rarely, I would rather catch and log to fix later without letting the consumer know (even with a nice error page) that something has broken.

Comment: @Valamas why is it bad practice? Also bad practice does not = not possible. Until just recently we couldn't Guid.tryparse, and that is not bad practice...

Comment: @JMD Alternative - Don't push code to production that is riddled with such problems?

Comment: @asawyer Being "riddled with problems" and having a few bugs that may or may not get caught by the QA team because they are so rare to get are two different things. I think you are being a bit harsh, and very unrealistic. Are you sheltered in academia or something?